# Django 2.0 CSS missing for chrome browser

Tags: python, css, django, web

I'm learning Django2.0 these days and tried the tutorial [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial02/). However, when it comes to the admin page part, the css style seems missing in Chrome browser:

[image]

However, when I visited 127.0.0.1:8000/admin in IE, Firefox or even Safari, everything went fine:
[image]

I'm using the latest version of Chrome.

Why? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What is the output from `manage.py runserver`? Can you see any errors in your developer tools in Chrome?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, there is a warning:"Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/x-css: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/admin/css/base.css" in the Chrome developer console

Comment: And what about `manage.py runserver`?

Comment: Two line: [19/Apr/2018 21:36:24] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[19/Apr/2018 21:36:24] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1855

Comment: I can see the output : "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1"  If I open the website in IE or Firefox, but it didn't show up in Chrome, so it may be the problem?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a Django issue, since it works in other browsers and there is no request for the static files in the runserver logs. I'm afraid I don't have any suggestions apart from the usual of clearing cache etc.

Comment: After clearing the Chrome cache, I can see the static file request in the runserver logs now, but the css style is still missing....

Comment: What do you see in the logs?

Comment: Same as it is in the other browsers, "GET /static/admin/css/XXX.css HTTP/1.1"

Comment: I've tried a Chrome plugin which can use the IE rendering engine directly within Chrome and as expected, everything goes fine now..

Answer (score 0):

Put staticfiles_dirs var in setting.py file

STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/path/to/project/static/',)